# Como retirar uma máscara JS de um input ao enviar o form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mask

Estou com um pequeno projeto feito em Java usando o SpringMVC e queria que um dos campos de um form tivesse a máscara de input monetária, mas quando dou o submit no form ele da erro no binding com o modelo, pois o campo está em BigDecimal e os caracteres colocados pela máscara vão junto. Já tentei alguns plugins feito em JQuery mas até agora nada adiantou...alguém conhece um plugin que sirva para mim? Algo que tire os pontos da máscara e substitua a vírgula por um ponto ao dar o submit...algo assim:

1.234,56 -------> 1234.56

Comment: VC pode remover o ponto (ou os pontos) e substituir a vírgula por ponto no próprio backend ao enviar o formulário e receber o valor.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar utilizando o método `replace`, por exemplo:

```
var a = "1.234,56"
a = a.replace(".", "")
a = a.replace(",", ".")
a = parseFloat(a)
```

No lugar da variável `a` utilize a variável que é retorna o valor de seu input.

Comment: Vlw Thales, deu certo mano, só tive que tirar o parseFloat pois estava dando conflito no Back com uma das regras de negócio, mas muito obrigado brother!

Comment: @NickFabrizzi não esqueça de marcar como respondida.